# How to adjust RGB in an old CRT monitor (Samsung SyncMaster 753s) where the on-screen controls do no have the provision?

Tags: crt-monitor

I just love CRTs. The have used LEDs and LCDs monitors but non of them have the high quality picture which a CRT monitor produce. In CRTs the color reproduction is very nice and also the brightness contrast levels are also worth mentioning. And high refresh rates... Whatever you say about CRTs are less.

Ok with that being said, I have many CRT monitors. Out of them a quite old one- Samsung SyncMaster 753s is the one which I am using currently for my daily computer use. The picture etc are fine. But it has a slight, very slight red tint in the picture which it produces. It was so, from the very beginning (I mean when I had bought the device for the first time). That time I was just a kid, was unable to notice this much detail..

I have other CRT monitors which have an RGB control in the pop up menu (on screen controls). But this monitor which I am talking of has no such RGB control in the pop up menu.

When I looked at the RGB adjustment section in the [service manual](https://documents.pub/document/syncmaster-753s-manual-service.html), there something is written about softgiz. But I do not quite understand what to do, as I have never heard of the software before and search about the software and how to use it does not even give any matching/suitable results.

I use linux mainly. My old windows machine, in the graphics properties adjust the RGB, contrast, brightness, pincushion,etc using a software (which was inbuilt in windows) but the settings did not use to remain permanent after restarting the monitor or restarting the computer. In linux I can use setting such as

`redshift -t 6500:6500 -g 0.75:1.0:1.0`

or use xrandr to use reduce the red, but this is done by operating system universally (I mean connecting it to another monitor with this setting causes a bluish image). I was looking for a monitor specific method.

Is it at all possible? If so how? Please guide me...

Comment: A quick look at the manual and it looks like there is a hardware interface board used by service technicians to tweak settings in the monitor using the softjig software.  It's probably a safe bet you don't have the he monitor Interface Board Ver. 2.0...  That said, I personally had a monitor that was being over-driven (hot) so I asked on the electrical engineering SE and built an L-pad attenuator (or voltage divider) for the RGB lines, you could do the same for just the Red.   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265020/how-to-attenuate-a-seemingly-overdriven-vga-signal